# Search multi dimensional array returning multiple results

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, php-5.5

I am trying to search a multi dimensional array, but the search only returns the first occurrence.

I have a multi dimensional array `$planned_housek`:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 14
            [title] => Titel 10
            [ruletext] => Regel 10
            [room] => 101
            [roomid] => 43
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 14
            [title] => Titel 10
            [ruletext] => Regel 10
            [room] => 102
            [roomid] => 42
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 14
            [title] => Titel 10
            [ruletext] => Regel 10
            [room] => 103
            [roomid] => 41
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 14
            [title] => Titel 10
            [ruletext] => Regel 10
            [room] => 104
            [roomid] => 44
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 14
            [title] => Titel 10
            [ruletext] => Regel 10
            [room] => 105
            [roomid] => 45
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [id] => 7
            [title] => TItel 3
            [ruletext] => Regel 3
            [room] => 101
            [roomid] => 43
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [id] => 13
            [title] => Titel 9
            [ruletext] => Regel 9
            [room] => 101
            [roomid] => 43
        )
)
```

When I search it with:

```
$planned_tasks = array_search($bkng_room, array_column($planned_housek, 'roomid'));
```

It returns the first occurrence of the `$bkng_room`.

Do I have to use a `for/foreach` to get an array of matches? Or is there a more elegant solution (PHP 5.5)?

I found this question, but the answer doesn't seem the most elegant solution:
[How to search a multidimensional array to return multiple keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31379702/how-to-search-a-multidimensional-array-to-return-multiple-keys).
Neither does this one: [Search multidimensional array for value and return new array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18454390/search-multidimensional-array-for-value-and-return-new-array)

In the docs on `array_search` I found:

> If needle is found in haystack more than once, the first matching key
>   is returned. To return the keys for all matching values, use
>   array_keys() with the optional search_value parameter instead.

But I'm not sure how to implement this in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope, This function is what you want !!

```
function array_search_inner ($array, $attr, $val, $strict = FALSE) {
  if (!is_array($array))
      return FALSE;
   foreach ($array as $key => $inner) {
      if (!is_array($inner))
           return FALSE;
      if (!isset($inner[$attr])) 
           continue;
      if ($strict) {
      if ($inner[$attr] === $val) 
           return $key;
    } else {
      if ($inner[$attr] == $val) return $key;
    }
  }
  return NULL;
}

// Example usage
$key = array_search_inner($array, 'id', 6);
print_r($key);
```